# VBA: Unable to get the Match property of the WorkSheet function class

Tags: excel, vba

Could someone please advise with the below code. I'd like to be able to find the column in which "Index" appears:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim d As Range
    Dim a As Variant

    Set d = Sheet2.Range("H349:M349")

    a = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match("Index", d, 0)

End Sub
```

But I get an error on the last line saying:

> Unable to get the Match property of the WorkSheet function class

Comment: Is the word "Index" the entire contents of the cell or just part of it?

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure the word "Index" (and only "Index") appears by itself in one of the cells within Sheet2 (which may not necessary be the same as Sheets("Sheet2")) H349:M349?

Match can be rather error prone in VBA, so I prefer to use the Range.Find method instead, which can be tested for Nothing (wasn't found):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rngFound As Range

    Set rngFound = Sheet2.Range("H349:M349").Find("Index", , xlValues, xlWhole)
    If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
        'Found a match
        MsgBox "Found a match at " & rngFound.Address
    Else
        'No matches
        MsgBox "No matches"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on xlValues and xlWhole please?

Comment: There's nothing error prone about MATCH? Match only works with one column ranges or arrays. MATCH is also much quicker than .Find in most cases. Also Application.Match is different to Worksheetfunction.Match as the former raises an error which can be caught.

Comment: xlValues is part of the xlFindLookIn Enumeration constants: xlComments, xlFormulas, and xlValues.  That tells the Find method where to look for the desired text (in this case "Index").  Because I specified xlValues, it will look at the cell values.  xlWhole is part of the XlLookAt Enumeration constants: xlPart and xlWhole.  That tells the Find method how to look for the desired text.  Because I specified xlWhole, it will try to find a whole match instead of a partial match.

Comment: @ooo, that should be  "one-column **or one-row** ranges or arrays". Good point on error-raising with `Application.Match`.

Comment: @DougGlancy - I meant to write one dimension arrays :) It should read one row ranges, one column ranges or single dimension arrays.